# ASP Identity Guid deserilization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using aspnet core with asp identity core and it's work well first hour. After an hour I got an exception
[image: Error snapshot]

> FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
>   (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

I don't know what can I have a bad configuration on this project. User entity has Guid Id, is it a problem?

Exception occured in every request to page. It's from first middleware in pipe `app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: Could you paste the code that gets called when this error occurs? That makes it easier to reason what might be wrong.

Comment: No code is called. Exception is from first middleware `app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: Hmm. Could it be something related to how the users are created or updated? Are you able to double check that the records in the database are correct?

Comment: @JonGStødle in DB everything is ok. User is created by `userManager.CreateAsync(user, password)`. User can login, but after an hour he got the exception. He has to remove cokiee `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` and login again. Then he has one new hour

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to tweak the expiration time of the cookie. Have a look at this answer about cookie expiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086645/how-to-set-asp-net-identity-cookies-expires-time#37090696

Comment: @JonGStødle I didn't change time expiration enywhere. But thank you for a tip