# How to set ASP.NET Identity auth cookie to expire at a particular date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity-2

[This answer seems pretty comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37090696/475766) but my app is using `ApplicationSignInManager` rather than `AuthenticationManager` which the answer uses, so it doesn't really apply to my app.

I'm trying to track my user logins (this is a proprietary website to be used internally by the client). So the client basically wants the login to work like a time card so the boss can see when staff are coming in to the office.

This functionality means I can't rely on persistent logins per ASP.NET Identity default behavior since it doesn't allow me to control if/when the login cookie expires.

What I'd like to do is to expire the cookie at 4am every day regardless of when the login occurs.

For that reason, [limiting the cookie's lifespan in configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28121081/475766) doesn't really satisfy my requirement either.

Here's my login code - pretty much standard stuff. Per the first answer, I hoped I could embed the expiry of the cookie into the `SignIn` method but since I'm using not using the `AuthenticationManager` for sign in, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with my current code.

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

// Note that this always persists the login cookie.
var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, true, shouldLockout: false);

// Evaluation of result below
```

If I need to change the way I'm doing logins here, that's fine; I'll just need some guidance on what changes to make (example code would be helpful).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody bothered to contribute to my question, I went around trying a bunch of stuff and came to my own answer:

Seems like [limiting the cookie's lifespan in configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28121081/475766) per the link in my question is actually the way to go.

In the auth config method, I determine how many hours there are between `now` and `4am tomorrow`, then I set the cookie's `ExpireTimeSpan` to that.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var expiryDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(4);
    var ts = expiryDate - DateTime.Now;
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(ts.Hours),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
}
```